# Como fixar uma img dentro de uma div?

Tags: html, css

Boa noite, estou fazendo uma lista de tarefas básica, e quero colocar um icone dentro do card de cada task para remover essa tarefa, porém, ele não está responsivo, quando eu diminuo a tela, ele sai pra fora da minha div, alguem pode me ajudar ?

**PROBLEMA:**

[image: problema]

```css
.card, .new-card{
    background-color: #c5e7eb;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 25%);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card  img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 350px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
            <p>Task</p>
            <img src="/xmark-solid.svg" alt="" id="remove-task" onclick="">
</div>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Obrigado a todos desde já.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @gabriel Morais, podes detalhar mais o problema pergunta? Eu não consegui reproduzir o problema. Eu copiei exatamente o seu código, testei no chrome, diminuindo a tela ao máximo, mesmo assim o ícone de `checkbox` não saiu da `div`. Na verdade, eu também não consegui identificar o problema na imagem que você postou.

Comment: Boa noite @VagnerSantosAraujo eu estou me referindo ao ícone em forma de X para remover a task, ele que está saindo da div, abraços…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que você precise

O detalhe foi adicionando o **justify-content: space-between;**. Ele faz com que os elementos seja distribuído igualmente na linha.

Na tag p, adicionei o display inline-block pra ele poder ficar na mesma linha que o checkbox, pois o p é do tipo **block**

Espero que tenha te ajudo!

```css
        .card{
            background-color: #c5e7eb;
            display: flex;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50%;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: calc(50% - 25%);
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        
        img {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        p{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
            <p>Task</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/106/106830.png" alt="icone-fechar" id="remove-task"           onclick="">
    </div>
```

Comment: cara ajudou demais, muito obrigado, não tinha pensado em envolver o input e o p numa div, salvou, valeu cara !!

Comment: Opa que bom, tamo junto!!